# How to manage sub-domains in node sites

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am creating my first MEAN2 app, but I stuck in mid. My site required one front-end (mysite.com) and one back-end(admin.mysite.com) to manage content. In future I would like to have a unique URL (*.mysite.com) for all the uses who will register at my site, for which there would not be a any directory in real. How could I acchieve it in a best way. To be more clear my requirement is -

```
mysite.com (original site)
admin.mysite.com (a sub-domain to be managed from same server.js file)
*.mysite.com (based on request host)


Note: I have created site using angular-cli are my structure is like below

-mysite(angular 4 app)
-admin(another angular 4 app)
-server.js
```

Comment: u can use a proxy server like nginx or haproxy.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not specific to node.js. However, in order to setup a domain successfully for your web app, you'll need 2 things:

1. **Web Server**

   This will manage for you virtual hostnames etc. I would advise you to look at setting up [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) as a reverse proxy in front of your node app.
2. **Domain provider**

   This will actually allow you to publicly use the domain *.mysite.com. Then you will have to setup a DNS Record, generally an A record, to point at your server IP Address.

This is very high level :) but should be enough to get you started.

**EDIT**
If you want to test locally just setup [nginx with a test server name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) to proxy_pass to your local nodejs app (i.e. http://localhost:3000) and create a host entry in your hosts file for that hostname.

Comment: Currently I am looking to setup at my local.

Comment: @AnkurVishnoi See the EDIT